# Can I make a secure "pure function" based password generator using python's random module?

Tags: python, random, cryptography, passwords, password-encryption

So I was looking for ways of managing my passwords without using a server-based password manager like LastPass and I came across https://lesspass.com. According to the website, this tool creates the same password for the given master password, username and website. I really liked the idea and decided to make my own proof of concept in python using the random module. I made this simple function:

```
    import random
    import string
    import os


    MASTER_PASS=os.environ.get('MASTER_PASS')


    def generate(platform, user, length):
        random.seed(platform+user+MASTER_PASS)
        letters=string.ascii_letters +string.digits + string.punctuation
        password=""
        for i in range(length):
            password+=random.choice(letters)
        print(password)



    generate("facebook", "xyz.abc", 32)
```

I think this should be secure enough as long as nobody knows my MASTER_PASSWORD but I cannot shake the feeling that this is somehow stupidly unsafe. Can anyone point out the glaring flaws in this approach and suggest some ways to improve the robustness?

**EDIT:**

I think some clarification is needed on my part.
I want to make a program where I can input my platform name, username and master password to generate a password. Also, it is imperative that I get the same password whenever I input the same combination. I am essentially trying to create a vault-less password manager that does not rely on any servers to store my passwords.

Comment: ok, I think I'm finally beginning to understand. Yeah, you're going to need to use a password hash like argon2 or pbkdf2. You're going to have write your own `choice` function to use the password-hash function. Or just copy the python source code.

Answer (score 2):

The `random` module is not cryptographically safe. You should use the [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) module instead.

> In particular, secrets should be used in preference to the default pseudo-random number generator in the random module, which is designed for modelling and simulation, not security or cryptography.

The API is identical, so your code will work.

As far as the approach is concerned, this is pretty much how other password generators work. Just keep in mind how much entropy is actually in the password (depends on `length` & the total size of `letters`).

Comment: I looked up the `secrets` module but it doesn't seem to have any `seed()` methods. See, I need to generate the same password for the given username, platform and master password. I just don't want anyone to work their way back from the generated password to my master password.

Comment: Any cryptographically secure PRNG won't have a `seed()` method. That's usually where the vulnerabilities come from.

Comment: Going by the [lesspass implementation](https://github.com/rdas1212/lesspass/blob/master/cli/lesspass/password.py) which is using a hash & using that to calculate some letters - which seems to be dubious as a secure password generator option at best. See this [HN discussion](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12889807) for details

Comment: I understand well enough why a secure PRNG will not have a `seed()` method. However, my problem requires me to get the same unique key when I have the corresponding platform, user and master_password.

Comment: To summarise: Your implementation is okay as a toy password generator. Just don't store any actual passwords with it. stick to established password managers.

Comment: You say: "However, my problem requires me to get the same unique key when I have the corresponding platform, user and master_password."  That looks a lot more like a hash than something random.  The point of random numbers is that they are random, they don't repeat in the same situation.  Try using a secure hash instead: SHA-256 or SHA3, whatever is in your crypto library.